# MessageBoxEx stops updation of actions

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I use Delphi 7 and my project has several non modal visible forms. The problem is if in one of them MessageBoxEx is called all actions of the application are not updated until MessageBoxEx’s form is closed. In my project it can broke business logic of application.

The TApplication.HandleMessage method is never called while MessageBoxEx's window is shown so it doesn’t call the DoActionIdle and Actions are not updated.

I think what I need is to catch a state of my application when it’s idle and update states of all actions.

First I implemented TApplication. OnIdle handler:

```
procedure TKernel.OnIdle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  {It’s only to switch off the standard updating from TApplication.Idle. It's to make the CPU usage lower while MessageBoxEx's window isn't shown }
 Done := False;
end;

implementation

var
  MsgHook: HHOOK;

{Here is a hook}
function GetMsgHook(nCode: Integer; wParam: Longint; var Msg: TMsg): Longint; stdcall;
var
  m: TMsg;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(MsgHook, nCode, wParam, Longint(@Msg));
  if (nCode >= 0) and (_instance <> nil) then
  begin
    {If there aren’t the messages in the application's message queue then the application is in idle state.}
    if not PeekMessage(m, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE) then
    begin
      _instance.DoActionIdle;
      WaitMessage;
    end;
  end;
end;

initialization
    MsgHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, @GetMsgHook, 0, GetCurrentThreadID);

finalization
  if MsgHook <> 0 then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(MsgHook);
```

Here is a method for updating states of all actions of the application. It’s just a modified version of TApplication.DoActionIdle:

```
type
  TCustomFormAccess = class(TCustomForm);

procedure TKernel.DoActionIdle;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Screen.CustomFormCount - 1 do
    with Screen.CustomForms[i] do
      if HandleAllocated and IsWindowVisible(Handle) and
        IsWindowEnabled(Handle) then
        TCustomFormAccess(Screen.CustomForms[i]).UpdateActions;
end;
```

It seems that the updating of the states happens much often than usually (I’m going to find out where is a problem using profiler).

Besides, CPU usage grows seriously when the mouse’s cursor is not over the application’s windows (about 25% on my DualCore Pentium).

What do you think about my problem and the way I try to solve it? Is it a good idea to use hooks or there is a better way to catch the application idle state? Do I rather need to use WH_CALLWNDPROCRET during setting the hook?

Why MessageBoxEx blocks TApplication.HandleMessage? Is there way to prevent this behavior? I’ve tried to call it with MB_APPLMODAL, MB_SYSTEMMODAL, MB_TASKMODAL flags but it didn’t help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MessageBox/Ex()` is a modal dialog, and as such it runs its own message loop internally since the calling thread's normal message loop is blocked.  `MessageBox/Ex()` receives any messages that are in the calling thread's message queue, and will dispatch them to target windows normally (so things like window-based timers still work, such as `TTimer`), but its modal message loop has no concept of VCL-specific messages, like action upates, and will discard them.  `TApplication.HandleMessage()` is only called by the main VCL message loop, the `TApplication.ProcessMessages()` method, and the `TForm.ShowModal()` method (this is why modal VCL Form windows do not suffer from this problem), none of which are called while `MessageBox/Ex()` is running (the same will be true for any OS modal dialog).

To solve your problem, you have a couple of choices:

1. set a thread-local message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` right before calling `MessageBox/Ex()`, then release the hook right after `MessageBox/Ex()` exits.  This allows you to look at every message that `MessageBox/Ex()` receives and dispatch them to VCL handlers as needed.  **DO NOT call `PeekMessage()`, `GetMessage()` or `WaitMessage()` inside of a message hook!**

   ```
   type
     TApplicationAccess = class(TApplication)
     end;

   function GetMsgHook(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
   var
     Msg: TMsg;
   begin
     if (nCode >= 0) and (wParam = PM_REMOVE) then
     begin
       Msg := PMsg(lParam)^;
       with TApplicationAccess(Application) do begin
         if (not IsPreProcessMessage(Msg))
           and (not IsHintMsg(Msg))
           and (not IsMDIMsg(Msg))
           and (not IsKeyMsg(Msg))
           and (not IsDlgMsg(Msg)) then
         begin
         end;
       end;
     end;
     Result := CallNextHookEx(MsgHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
   end;

   function DoMessageBoxEx(...): Integer;
   var
     MsgHook: HHOOK;
   begin
     MsgHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, @GetMsgHook, 0, GetCurrentThreadID);
     Result := MessageBoxEx(...);
     if MsgHook <> 0 then UnhookWindowsHookEx(MsgHook);
   end;
   ```
2. move the `MessageBox/Ex()` call to a separate worker thread so the calling thread is free to process messages normally.  If you need to wait for the result of `MessageBox/Ex()`, such as when prompting the user for input, then you can use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` to wait for the thread to terminate while allowing the waiting thread to call `Application.ProcessMessages()` whenever there are pending messages to process.

   ```
   type
     TMessageBoxThread = class(TThread)
     protected
       procedure Execute; override;
       ...
     public
       constructor Create(...);
     end;

   constructor TMessageBoxThread.Create(...);
   begin
     inherited Create(False);
     ...
   end;

   function TMessageBoxThread.Execute;
   begin
     ReturnValue := MessageBoxEx(...);
   end;

   function DoMessageBoxEx(...): Integer;
   var
     Thread: TMessageBoxThread;
     WaitResult: DWORD;
   begin
     Thread := TMessageBoxThread.Create(...);
     try
       repeat
         WaitResult := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, Thread.Handle, False, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
         if WaitResult = WAIT_FAILED then RaiseLastOSError;
         if WaitResult = WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 then Application.ProcessMessages;
       until WaitResult = WAIT_OBJECT_0;
       Result := Thread.ReturnVal;
     finally
       Thread.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! As for me the first solution looks more attractive. Unfortunately both of them suppose that I need to find all calls of MessageBox and replace. But I think it won't be too difficult.

Comment: what is IsPreProcessMessage? Is it a method from any older version of Delphi?

Comment: Hmm. I think the first approach is not correct, is it? TApplication calls DoActionIdle (updates action) when there are not messages in queue (there are not any VCL messages to update actions) and app become idle while the hook are executed when MessageBox's window receives some messages. It's not the same I guess.

Comment: `IsPreProcessMessage()` allows an MDI MainForm or the currently focused `TWinControl` to get first dibs at processing the message. It was introduced in D2005. As for the VCL's idle handling, in order to invoke it in the first solution, you can call the public `TApplication.DoApplicationIdle()` method when needed. The trick is determining when to call it, since you cannot detect when the modal dialog's internal message loop goes idle. I would probably use a short one-time timer, where each received message (re)sets the timer, then it calls `DoApplicationIdle()` when it elapses.